# Cover entire row with a single column - width issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table, repeater

I have repeater & table controls. My table has one column. When I run the code each cell in the row covers around 25% (based on content of cell) of the row & background color also changes for that area only. I want cell to cover the entire row. Following is the code. I set the column width to 100%, however it did not solve the issue. I do not want to hard code the width for cell.

```
        <div style="overflow-y: auto; width: 100%; height: 395px; border: 0px solid #3C454F; background-color: #FFFBE6; border: 0px solid #3C454F;">
            <asp:Repeater ID="TestList" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table>
                </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: aqua; padding-top: 5px">
                        <td style="width: 100%;">
                            <%#Container.DataItem%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: white; padding-top: 5px">
                        <td style="width: 100%;">
                            <%#Container.DataItem%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
```

Comment: See "rowspan" and "colspan" attributes i guess.

Comment: You need to assign the full width 100% to Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    <div style="overflow-y: auto; width: 100%; height: 395px; border: 0px solid #3C454F; background-color: #FFFBE6; border: 0px solid #3C454F;">
        <asp:Repeater ID="TestList" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table style="width:100%;">
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color: aqua; padding-top: 5px">
                    <td style="width: 100%;">
                        <%#Container.DataItem%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color: white; padding-top: 5px">
                    <td style="width: 100%;">
                        <%#Container.DataItem%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```